# Angular -How to display or loop though array of arrays

Tags: angular, multidimensional-array, angular-material, ngfor, ng-container

I would like to display the list of arrays that contain arrays inside.

I have arrays as below with dummy data

```
[
    [
        {
            "date": "September 11",
            "User": "ABC",
            "Action": "Added"
            
        },
        {
            "date": "September 11",
            "User": "asd",
            "Action": "Removed"
            
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "date": "September 8",
            "User": "sdf",
            "Action": "Added"
            
        },
        {
            "date": "September 8",
            "User": "rty",
            "Action": "Updated"
           
        },
        {
            "date": "September 8",
            "User": "pol",
            "Action": "Removed"           
        }
    ]
]
```

I am trying to get data as below with angular mat table in the html page based on the date

September 11

- ABC    Added
- asd    Removed

September 8

- sdf    Added
- rty    Updated
- pol    Removed

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through each items in the list (so every events of the same date). Then, once inside you can loop another time through every event of said date.

Basically, you only need two loops.

Here's an example with a console.log() in javascript with the data you provided:

```
let i = 0;
let j = 0;
let date = "";

for (i = 0; i<array.length; i++){
    for (j=0; j < array[i].length; j++){
        if (date == ""){
           date = array[i][j]['date'];
           console.log(array[i][j]['date']);
        }
        console.log(array[i][j]['User'] + " " + array[i][j]['Action']);
    }
date = "";
}
```

And the result:

[image]

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let dataArray of data">
  <div *ngIf="dataArray.length > 0">
    <h2>{{ dataArray[0].date }}</h2>
    <table>
      <tr *ngFor="let item of dataArray">
        <td>{{ item.User }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.Action }}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```